# Handling volley failed requests

Tags: android, request, android-volley

Is it possible to retry a network request using Android Volley manually using Volley TAG? I understand that I can set my own RetryPolicy in which case Volley retries a request. I want to know if I can re-send a network request using Volley TAG?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a `RetryPolicy` on the request object. See `com.android.volley.Request.setRetryPolicy()` and the constructor for `DefaultRetryPolicy`.

```
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20 * 1000, 1, 1.0f));
```

The `DefaultRetryPolicy` class takes first argument called initial timeout, this can be used to specify a request timeout. Second argument called maximum retry count is 1 so that volley does not retry the request after the timeout has been exceeded.

If you want to retry failed requests (due to timeout) you can specify that too using the code above, **just increase the retry count**. Note the last argument, it allows you to specify a backoff multiplier which can be used to implement “exponential backoff” that some RESTful services recommend.

Source : [Retrying failed requests and customizing request Timeout](http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/)